# How to get just certain data from azure blob storage in Azure Data Factory performing copy activity with destination as SQL database?

Tags: sql, azure, etl, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to perform Copy Activity inside Azure Data Factory where the source is Blob and destination is MySql database.

I do not want certain data to be copied during that activity and that can be determined by reading First key value Element of the Blob JSON.

Or maybe if it is not possible to stop reading all the BLOB data then atleast while writing inside the SQL table I want just some specific data.

I saw that there is Pre-copy Script in the copy activity. Can someone give an idea how to use it or what kind of script I can write there?

Answer (score 0):

The pre copy script doesn't work for your requirement. you can use dataflow with a filter transformation to cleanse your data.

[image]

The doc is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when I make a new data flow , i cannot select the already existing Blob source while choosing the Source 1 in Data flow. I also tried to create a new blob source but i cannot choose JSON format in that, just the text file which is not helpful for me for parsing.

Comment: JSON is not supported in dataflow currently.

Comment: So can you suggest me a way out for this?